# How to add an event listener to all items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener, queryselector

so this is noobie .. but i am trying to complete a challenge with more due diligence than just downloading the answer,

my current html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Drum Kit</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
      <div class="set">
        <button class="w drum">w</button>
        <button class="a drum">a</button>
        <button class="s drum">s</button>
        <button class="d drum">d</button>
        <button class="j drum">j</button>
        <button class="k drum">k</button>
        <button class="l drum">l</button>
      </div>
    
    
      <footer>
        Made with ❤️ in London.
      </footer>
      <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
```

my javascript codes :

```
   document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    function handleClick() {
        alert("I got clicked!");
    }
    
    
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

essentially, the current code is running the event listener
for the first and last item of the array only, trying to add it to all 6 but am stuck

thanks to all

Comment: Can you please also share the relevant parts of the HTML? It's best to do this together with your already provided JS in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of attaching listeners to each button, add *one* to the container (`set`)  and, using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/), let that listener capture all the events that "bubble up" the DOM from its child elements, and call a function.

```js
const set = document.querySelector('.set');
set.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {  
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    const { textContent } = e.target;
    console.log(`Banging the ${textContent} drum!`);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button class="w drum">w</button>
  <button class="a drum">a</button>
  <button class="s drum">s</button>
  <button class="d drum">d</button>
  <button class="j drum">j</button>
  <button class="k drum">k</button>
  <button class="l drum">l</button>
</div>
<footer>
  Made with ❤️ in London.
</footer>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: whoa, above and beyond.. thanks man. This wasnt even the answer the instructor gave! lmao cheers to your greatness

Comment: thanks man, for the advice and words of encouragement!

Answer (score 4):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".drum").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", handleClick));
```

You need a `forEach` to run some code on **all** elements.

Comment: thanks, i still couldnt figure out how to pass in the right data for the elements so i uploaded the rest of the code,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".drum").forEach(function(drum){
 drum.addEventListener("click" , function(event){
     console.log(event);
 }) 
})
```